# Google Cloud Api + vk module + python 3

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, google-cloud

Вот этот код вылетает на Google Cloud Api с ошибкой

```
'module' object has no attribute 'Session'
```

и `name 'api' is not defined`

vk модуль устанавливался так: сначала загрузил и распаковал архив с исходниками [отсюда](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vk/2.0.2), затем командой `python setup.py install --user` установил. Что не так и как с этим бороться? Заранее благодарен

```
#импорт библиотек для использования URL
import urllib
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

import logging
import logging.config

import os, vk
from time import *

from all_skips import *
access_token1='xxxxxxx'

#...here is declared some function...

logging.config.fileConfig('log_config_news')
logger = logging.getLogger("root")
logger.info("program started")
print("program started")
try:
    session = vk.Session(access_token=access_token1)
    api = vk.API(session)
except Exception as E:
    logger.error(E)
while True:
    receive()
    now = time()
    if len(all_clients) > 0:
        for i in all_clients:
            i.check()
    if (time() - now) < 0.3:
        sleep(0.3 - (time() - now))
```

Comment: Пара замечаний: if без скобок, `if len(all_clients) > 0:` заменитт на `if all_clients:`, а с учетом вашего кода можно просто убрать условие, если контейнер пустой, цикл просто невыполнится, `logger.error(E)` заменить на `logger.exception('Error:')`

Answer (score 0):

всё оказалось просто: в Google Cloud Api по умолчанию нет pip3. Установка описанная выше также ставит для python 2.x.
дабы установить всё, что нужно надо выполнить такие команды:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
sudo easy_install3 pip
pip3 install vk --user
```